# Check for word match count in random letters

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a string of 500 random letters and a 10,000 dictionary [word list](https://github.com/first20hours/google-10000-english).

I want to check the letters for word matches.

If there are 5 matches or greater I want it to return the list of matched words.

However this `foreach` and `Contains.()` doesn't seem to work correctly or return correct matches. It is also returning partial matches and single letters.

---

```
// 500 Random Letters
string letters = "bliduuwfhbgphwhsyzjnlfyizbjfeeepsbpgplpbhaegyepqcjhhotovnzdtlracxrwggbcmjiglasjvmscvxwazmutqiwppzcjhijjbguxfnduuphhsoffaqwtmhmensqmyicnciaoczumjzyaaowbtwjqlpxuuqknxqvmnueknqcbvkkmildyvosczlbnlgumohosemnfkmndtiubfkminlriytmbtrzhwqmovrivxxojbpirqahatmydqgulammsnfgcvgfncqkpxhgikulsjynjrjypxwvlkvwvigvjvuydbjfizmbfbtjprxkmiqpfuyebllzezbxozkiidpplvqkqlgdlvjbfeticedwomxgawuphocisaejeonqehoipzsjgbfdatbzykkurrwwtajeajeornrhyoqadljfjyizzfluetynlrpoqojxxqmmbuaktjqghqmusjfvxkkyoewgyckpbmismwyfebaucsfueuwgio"

// Dictionary Words List
string[] words = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\dictionarywords.txt").Split('\n');

// Word Matches List
List<string> matches = new List<string>();


// Check for Word matches in Letters
foreach (var x in words)
{
    // Add to list if match
    if (letters.Contains(x))
    {
        matches.Add(x);
    }
}

// Return Matched Words if 5 or greater
if (matches.Count() >= 5)
{
    textBox.Text = string.Join("\n", matches);
}
```

---

#### Examples

Word matches found by eye:

- lid
- hot
- gum
- hose
- hat

Code Match Returns:

- my
- up
- so
- c
- et
- ms
- am
- me
- s
- x
- n
- b
- ...

Comment: What's happening in the debugger when it returns a single letter or gibberish?

Comment: Those matches are indeed in your string. Without seeing your dictionary, I would assume they are in your dictionary as well. All those matches _are_ proper English words, letters or otherwise expected entries in a dictionary.

Comment: @oerkelens I think you're right https://raw.githubusercontent.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/master/google-10000-english.txt

Comment: So your code works as designed?

Comment: @oerkelens I'm looking for a better dictionary list, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working as intended. It IS finding those words, but it's also finding additional words. I'd suggest taking out the words you don't want to show up in a search. For example, a lot of people use this in a profanity filter. So if a sentence contains a curse word, it omits the word because it found it in the dictionary of curse words. Give it a try with a much smaller list with words you've put in yourself and test the results. Try changing those words to other words?